# Xcode: View Console History After Cleared?

Tags: xcode, console, history

How can I see the Xcode console history? I accidentally cleared it by running the application again and am wondering if I can get back what was cleared.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xcode 11:

In the Navigator, press the "Report navigator" button (the speech bubble), then click on your previous run sessions. You can see all your previous console logs.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Xcode console output is logged in the system log. You can search the system log from the console with grep:

```
# view last 2000 lines of the system log
sudo tail -n2000 /private/var/log/system.log

# search system log for YourApp
sudo grep YourApp /private/var/log/system.log

# watch the system log as it's being written and filter for YourApp
sudo tail -f /private/var/log/system.log | grep YourApp
```

Comment: Tight! Thanks! I started a bounty to award you more points :). But, SO said I have to wait 23 hours to award it to you. :/

Comment: Doesnt work at all... I need my prints but nothing is displayed what I printed. Why?

Comment: What YourApp means? the name of my app or name of the catalog?

Comment: Hod do I recover my console prints?